# Cannot access a disposed object in unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, dispose

I have function to mock http client:

```
private void MockClient(HttpStatusCode status, HttpContent content = null)
 {
   _client
     .Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
     .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage {StatusCode = status, Content = content})).Verifiable();
 }
```

And I use it tests like this:

```
        [Fact]
        public async void Get_SerializerFailure_Throws()
        {
            var content = new MemoryStream(new byte[5]);
            MockClient(HttpStatusCode.OK, new StreamContent(content));

            _jsonSerializer.Setup(x => x.DeserializeFromStream<Dto>(It.IsAny<Stream>())).Throws<JsonReaderException>();
            await Assert.ThrowsAsync<JsonReaderException>(() => _sut.GetAllAsync());
        }
```

here I get error:

```
 typeof(System.ObjectDisposedException): Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent'.
```

However, if I mock client directly in the test like this it works and doesn't throw this error:

```
        [Fact]
        public async void Get_ProtobufSerializerFailure_Throws()
        {
            var content = new MemoryStream(new byte[5]);
            _client
                .Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage {StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = new StreamContent(content)})).Verifiable();


            _protobufSerializer.Setup(x => x.DeserializeFromStream<Dto>(It.IsAny<Stream>())).Throws<JsonReaderException>();
            await Assert.ThrowsAsync<JsonReaderException>(() => _sut.GetAllAsync());
        }
```

I do not get what is the difference here and why one way works while other does not and how ti fix my mock method.

I am testing these methods:

```
private async Task<Object> GetLatest()
        {
            using (var response = await _client.Get($"{_serviceUrl}", CancellationToken.None))
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                return _jsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream<Objects>(stream)?.Items.Last();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<(ulong key, Dto item)>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            var latest = await GetLatest();

            using (var response = await _client.Get(url,CancellationToken.None))
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (var decompressionStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                var result = _protobufSerializer.DeserializeFromStream<Dto>(decompressionStream);
                return result.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Comment: First avoid using `async void`, use `async Task`. Second, show the subject under test so we get a better understanding of what you are trying to test

Comment: The problem is with scope. In the first one the stream content is passed as a variable to the returns function and will be disposed of the first time the `Get` is called by `GetLatest` and the response is disposed. In the second example a new content stream will be created each time the returns function is invoked.

Comment: But it works fine when I run the program, but doesn't work in unit tests

Comment: Because in the program the actual client returns different responses. In your unit test your mock is returning the same client response content every time.

Comment: `MockClient(HttpStatusCode.OK, new StreamContent(content));` doesn't that set new content? So I shouldn't use this function and use `_client.Setup...` in each test (because that way works)?

Comment: `Content = content` inside of the function is going to give the same content to every response returned by the mocked client. In this case your subject under test is disposing of its response which will in turn dispose of the content

Comment: But I am passing different content like this: `var content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(LatestObject));
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different between these two test setups is how many instances of `StreamContent` class are created during the test execution.

- The first setup creates multiple instance of `HttpResponseMessage` class with the reference to the same single instance of `StreamContent` passed as a parameter to `MockClient` method.

```
.Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage {StatusCode = status,
    Content = content}))
```

- The second setup also creates multiple instance of `HttpResponseMessage` class, one per `_client.Get` method execution, but every `HttpResponseMessage` instance has own instance of `StreamContent`.

```
.Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage {StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StreamContent(content)}))
```

In the provided code, the `_client.Get` method is called twice during the single test execution. The first time in `GetLatest` method and the second time in `GetAllAsync` method. Each method reads response content and disposes it. As result, in case of the first setup, `GetAllAsync` method receives `ObjectDisposedException` on attempt to read response content as a stream, as the single instance of response content has been already disposed in `GetLatest` method.

All disposable objects should be created as many times as they are retrieved and disposed in the code under test.

---

### **SOLUTION 1**

As a possible solution, the `MockClient` method should be changed to accept byte array instead of StreamContent and create separate StreamContent and MemoryStream instances for each `HttpResponseMessage` response.

```
private void MockClient(HttpStatusCode status, byte[] content = null)
{
   _client
      .Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
      .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(
         new HttpResponseMessage
         {
            StatusCode = status, 
            Content = content == null 
               ? null 
               : new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(content))
         }))
      .Verifiable();
}

[Fact]
public async Task Get_SerializerFailure_Throws()
{
   MockClient(HttpStatusCode.OK, new byte[5]);

   _jsonSerializer.Setup(x => x.DeserializeFromStream<Dto>(It.IsAny<Stream>())).Throws<JsonReaderException>();
   await Assert.ThrowsAsync<JsonReaderException>(() => _sut.GetAllAsync());
}
```

---

### **SOLUTION 2**

Another option is to pass `Func<StreamContent>` delegate to `MockClient` method.

```
private void MockClient(HttpStatusCode status, Func<StreamContent> content = null)
{
   _client
      .Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
      .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(
         new HttpResponseMessage
         {
            StatusCode = status, 
            Content = content == null 
               ? null 
               : content()
         }))
      .Verifiable();
}

[Fact]
public async Task Get_SerializerFailure_Throws()
{
   MockClient(HttpStatusCode.OK, () => new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(new byte[5])));

   _jsonSerializer.Setup(x => x.DeserializeFromStream<Dto>(It.IsAny<Stream>())).Throws<JsonReaderException>();
   await Assert.ThrowsAsync<JsonReaderException>(() => _sut.GetAllAsync());
}
```